# Is it possible to find the closed form expression for the largest eigenvalue of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As we know, a matrix multiplied by a diagonal matrix can be viewed as a scaling of itself. And multiplied by a unitary matrix can be viewed as a rotation from the original matrix. So now I'm wondering how to analytically find the largest eigenvalue of the following mentioned matrix.

Could anyone please give any inspirations? Many thanks!

$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{\Lambda_G V \Lambda_p V}^H\mathbf{\Lambda_G^H}$, where $\mathbf{\Lambda_G}$ is a complex diagonal matrix, and 
$\mathbf{\Lambda_p}$ is real and its diagonal elements are all non-negative.
$\mathbf{V}$ is a unitary matrix such that $\mathbf{VV}^H=\mathbf{I}$.

[The problem discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1brh.jpg)

Comment: So $\Lambda_P$ is real? "Non-negative" does not make any sense for complex matrices.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... already fixed it. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible when the matrices involved are 2 x 2.  [See here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1JunjKxazANVlU2eUttc2tlSDA) for closed form solutions to 2 x 2 SVDs, and for the problem posed here, the singular values and the eigenvalues are the same thing.  Likely doable for 3 x 3, since that should reduce to solving a third order polynomial, and there are (very messy) closed form solutions for doing that.  Beyond that, good luck - you have entered 
the mathematics wastelands...

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond! I went through your paper and that's amazing! Now I think I need some time to digest it...

Comment: Even fourth order is solvable. Not so messy as one generally thinks.

Comment: I have always wondered whether it is possible in general, once one understands the underlying structure of a unitary matrix [see here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1JunjKxazANLUhiaVhiejB5eDQ) so that the problem can be attacked via a decimation approach.